# Why does command line say process stopped after running in background?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, background-process

I have a script that takes 10 minutes to run:

```
php /path/to/script.php
```

If I run it as above it prints out feedback along the way like so:

```
> php /path/to/script.php
1    file_a.txt processed in 4.3 seconds
2    file_b.txt processed in 3.5 seconds
...
```

But I'd like to run several of these processes in parallel like so:

```
> php /path/to/script.php &>/dev/null &
> php /path/to/script.php &>/dev/null &
```

But every time I do this, I see that the previous one is stopped like this:

```
> php /path/to/script.php &>/dev/null &
[1] 11206
> php /path/to/script.php &>/dev/null &
[1]+  Stopped                 php /path/to/script.php &>/dev/null
```

**How can I run many of these scripts at once?**

So far I've tried:

```
> php /path/to/script.php &
> php /path/to/script.php &/dev/null &
> nohup php /path/to/script.php &
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

I also have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` set and no errors show up when running manually.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to generous commenters, the following works:

```
php /path/to/script.php < /dev/null &
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: better think which is your real goal... Why running two copies of the same program at once? You could probably obtain a better (and cheaper in terms of system resource usage) result...

Comment: It seems that your script tries to read from stdin. A process trying to read from the console cannot run in the background. Maybe you should add `< /dev/null`...

Comment: How can I evaluate if / how my "script tries to read from stdin"? I also tried appending `< /dev/null` to the lines above to no avail. Can you write the entire line as you believe it should work?

Comment: php /path/to/script.php </dev/null & <Enter>
php /path/to/script.php </dev/null &

Comment: `php /path/to/script.php < /dev/null &` FTW! Thanks. Please submit as answer.

Comment: And `php /path/to/script.php < /dev/null &>/dev/null &` to silence the script

Answer (score 0):

```
php /path/to/script.php < /dev/null
```

Or silence the script with:

```
php /path/to/script.php < /dev/null &>/dev/null &
```